# Trello like horizontal scrolling on mouse drag in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

Does Angular offer a way to implement horizontal scrolling on mouse down/drag? Thus far, I have tried all the related solutions but have not found the closest one to my desired approach!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested "Dragula"?
[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dragula)

[image]

You can do not only vertical drag&drop, but horizontal as well if you change the direction with the option:

```
direction:'horizontal'
```

Answer (score 1):

try [SwiperJs](https://swiperjs.com/)
it already support angular component's